# outcome depends on order of variable initialization?

Tags: c, microcontroller, atmega

I am experimenting with SPI on an ATmega16a and therefore initialize the following variables (outside of any method) in C:

```
uint8_t refreshCounter = 0;
uint8_t sendBuffer[32] = {};
volatile uint8_t doSend = FALSE;
char lineBuffer[20] = {};
```

With these lines everything works as expected, but when I switch the last two lines, my program stops working (at least the remote SPI module does not answer):

```
uint8_t refreshCounter = 0;
uint8_t sendBuffer[32] = {};
char lineBuffer[20] = {}; 
volatile uint8_t doSend = FALSE;
```

*What is wrong with these definitions?* Why is the order important?

`doSend` is `volatile` because it is used within an interrupt handler. All other variables are only accessed within the endless main-loop. Tell me, if you need more code.

Comment: Were I to guess, you're program is overrunning either `lineBuffer` or `sendBuffer` somewhere. Speculative, yes, but can't say either way without seeing code.

Comment: You probably have undefined behavior going on somewhere else in your code. C doesn't allow empty braces for array initializers, so your code should be `uint8_t sendBuffer[32] = {0};` (for both arrays), but I don't see how that can cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: @Praetorian I tried it with `{0}`, but it does not have an effect. Another thing I saw: When initializing it without assigning anything I cannot use the `sendBuffer` (which means then `sendBuffer[0] = 0xff` does not have an effect). Weird things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning @WhozCraig's comment into an answer: Yes, I wrote 21 bytes into my lineBuffer with the following line

```
sprintf(lineBuffer, "%20c", ' ');
```

because `sprintf` appends a trailing null space. My fault.

Thank you @WhozCraig!

Answer (score 1):

Strange behaviors depending on variables order usually are symptoms of memory corruption. It's not noticable in the PC world, where memory protection is something normal, but in bare-metal programs it's quite common.

If your program crashes because you changed `short` to `int` somewhere or reversed order of variables in some structure - start hunting memory corruption. You wont be disappointed. :)